# How to show projects in separate windows in JetBrains WebStorm 2020.3.2

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

The latest update changed the way projects are shown in WebStorm. Previously they were shown in separate windows, now they are "bundled" together in one window (even when "New Window" option is used when opening a project). How to turn this off?

[image: WebStorm with two projects open in one window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mac **System Preferences-> General**, try setting **Prefer tabs when opening documents** to ***never***

Comment: Thanks. This works. Do you know what other applications could be affected by this setting?

Comment: this option affects all apps, see https://support.apple.com/en-za/guide/mac-help/mchla4695cce/11.0/mac/11.0